# Google Chrome Create Extra space on Right Side of My Website

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, responsive-design

I am working on a Responsive Layout for my Website. I have an extra space on the Right side for English and Left side for Arabic Version, I can not exactly determine were does it come from. this responsive it looks good in FireFox but in Google Chrome creates it.
 link of my website :
http://kirkuknow.com/english/
change the website to mobile version at inspect element

Best[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lleRN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**English version** - It seems to me that the problem is in the div with id #subNews in the mobile view of the website. It contains several divs with the class .subNewsContainer, which are empty, but still hold their widths.
Once I removed #subNews via the Chrome developer tools, the right side blank white space was gone.
Maybe the problem here is that you're not handling that subNews part correctly in the mobile version? You're not rendering any content, but still rendering the divs.

**Edit (adding the root cause for arabic version):** - it seems the problem in the Arabic version is different. There, the div with id #langbar (language bar?) has a fixed absolute position from the right (600px), and therefore goes a lot to the left, therefore creating that blank white space. Removing it from Chrome developer tools fixed the problem, so you should fix the stylesheet for that div and the ones below it.

**General tip**: the easiest way to find these issues is just start searching in developer tools. Start deleting each div in the DOM tree, until the problem is resolved. Once you deleted an element and the problem was resolved, you can dig deeper into understanding why that specific div causes the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dear Tomer Sh... For English Version Your Suggestion is Working Fine But For Arabic and Kurdish Version The Problems Still Not Solved Please Can You Check Arabic or Kurdish Version to help me..I appreciate your help.

Comment: Added the root cause analysis for the Arabic version as well. Please mark as resolved if the answer helped you. Good luck :)

Comment: It's works fine...thanks a lot....